# Suppress Azure Stop-AzureRMVM cmdlet warning message box

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

When I tried to stop the virtual machine on Azure using Powershell cmdlet Stop-AzureRMVM (new ARM one), I get the message box as shown below.
Problem with this, If I run this in the batch statements, I get this message box / prompt for each statement where VM is shutdown. How do I suppress this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the -Force switch should suppress all questions of that nature, not just for Azure-related cmdlets, but all cmdlets in general.

Answer (score 1):

look at the [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603483.aspx) and use `-force`